# Using curly braces to value-initialize temporary as initializer to static data member causes error

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

This very simple code code gives an error in [GCC 6.0](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/gwA6FAW5G0a6id96):

```c++
template<class T>
struct S {
    // error: cannot convert 'T' to 'const int' in initialization
    static const int b = T{};
};

int main() {
}
```

Strangely, if I use regular braces instead (`T()`) then the code compiles. Is this a bug? The code compiles fine in clang.

Comment: I don't have an answer, I can only suggest a possible reason. T{} means that T is not a basic type, therefore there is no conversion to int. But when you use T(), T can be int or whatever.

Comment: @SergiiKhaperskov `T{}` is colloquially referred to as "uniform-initialization" (though the standard doesn't use the term). Any data type whether built-in or not can be initialized using a pair of curly braces. This was added in C++11 mainly to circumvent the [Most Vexing Parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) problem.

Comment: Got it. I did not know basic types can be initialized with {}. I thought it was only for objects, arrays and containers. Sorry for taking your time :)

Comment: It looks like a gcc bug to me.

Comment: Isn't `T{}` supposed to warn against missing initializer? Could that be the case here?

Comment: @tsuki I'm not sure what you mean. `= T{}` is the initializer.

Comment: `static const int b = T{};` attempts an implicit conversion between `T` and `int`. In order to do that, you first construct `T{}` which have empty brackets. I remember getting warnings about missing initializer in GCC in contexts like this, but I'm unable to reproduce them, so nevermind.

Comment: @tsuki The template isn't instantiated yet so no implicit conversion can take place until `T` is known. `T{}` and `T()` [value-initialize](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) a temporary of type `T`. It is well-formed for any default-constructible `T`. If `T()` works then `T{}` should work.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that `T()` works is because the compiler interprets it as a function declaration which takes no argument. The compiling would be done with just an explicit casting:

```
static const int b = (const int) T{};
```

Comment: That's simply not true. There's no way this syntax can be interpreted as a function declaration. `T()` is effectively equivalent to `T{}`. It creates an *object*, not a function.

Comment: So simply investigate more to see that, before assuming.